# Standard error of mean - under measurement error

Tags: mean, standard-error, measurement-error, errors-in-variables

I have two observations of a normally distributed random variable:
$$
X_1 = 0.02   \\  
X_2 = 0.10
$$
Obviously the sample mean equals 0.06, and the standard error of the mean (SEM) is equal to 0.04.

Now things get messy. The observations themselves can only be measured with noise, e.g. due to bad instruments. Let the measurement error of $X_1$ equal 0.04 and of $X_2$ equal 0.02.

How can I calculate an adjusted SEM that accounts for the measurement error? Intuitively, it should be greater than 0.04 in this example. When measurement error becomes smaller, the SEM should converge to its value in absence of measurement error.